# Keep \n in string content and write to one line

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code for parsing some HTML. I need to save the output (html result) as a single line of code with the escaped character sequences there such as `\n` but I'm either getting a representation I can't use from `repr()` because of the single quotes or the output is being written to multiple lines like so (interpreting the escape sequences):

```
<section class="prog__container">
 <span class="prog__sub">Title</span>
 <p>PEP 336 - Make None Callable</p>
 <span class="prog__sub">Description</span>
 <p>
 <p>
 <code>
      None
     </code>
     should be a callable object that when called with any
 arguments has no side effect and returns
     <code>
      None
     </code>
     .
    </p>
 </p>
 </section>
```

What I require (including the escape sequences):

```
<section class="prog__container">\n <span class="prog__sub">Title</span>\n <p>PEP 336 - Make None Callable</p>\n <span class="prog__sub">Description</span>\n <p>\n <p>\n <code>\n      None\n     </code>\n     should be a callable object that when called with any\n arguments has no side effect and returns\n     <code>\n      None\n     </code>\n     .\n    </p>\n </p>\n </section>
```

**My Code**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for match in soup.findAll(['div']):
    match.unwrap()

for match in soup.findAll(['a']):
    match.unwrap()

html = soup.contents[0]
html = str(html)
html = html.splitlines(True)
html = " ".join(html)
html = re.sub(re.compile("\n"), "\\n", html)
html = repl(html) # my current solution works, but unusable
```

The above is my solution, but an object representation is no good, I need the string representation. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't use just `repr`?

```
a = """this is the first line
this is the second line"""
print repr(a)
```

Or even (if I clear with your issue of exact output without literal quotes)

```
print repr(a).strip("'")
```

Output:

```
'this is the first line\nthis is the second line'
this is the first line\nthis is the second line
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import bs4

html = '''<section class="prog__container">
 <span class="prog__sub">Title</span>
 <p>PEP 336 - Make None Callable</p>
 <span class="prog__sub">Description</span>
 <p>
 <p>
 <code>
      None
     </code>
     should be a callable object that when called with any
 arguments has no side effect and returns
     <code>
      None
     </code>
     .
    </p>
 </p>
 </section>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
str(soup)
```

out:

```
'<html><body><section class="prog__container">\n<span class="prog__sub">Title</span>\n<p>PEP 336 - Make None Callable</p>\n<span class="prog__sub">Description</span>\n<p>\n</p><p>\n<code>\n      None\n     </code>\n     should be a callable object that when called with any\n arguments has no side effect and returns\n     <code>\n      None\n     </code>\n     .\n    </p>\n</section></body></html>'
```

There are more complex way to output the html code in the [Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#non-pretty-printing)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The same problem exists here as using the `repr()` function regarding the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

r = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read(), 'html.parser')
html = str(soup)
```

This will give your html as one string and lines separated by \n